# Provide security wallet

Tags: go-ethereum, security, addresses

I have a service where users can buy my product. Besides paying by card, I want to be able to allow users to pay in `ETH`. I think that it will correctly generate addresses for each user so that it is possible to follow the balance.On the sever I have run `geth`, and users get their addresses via the `rpc` request. But if someone is hacked server, he can withdraw all amounts. How can I can I provide secure wallet?

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [HD wallets](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki). You'll be able to store your seed words safely offline, put the Master public key on a server and generate receiving addresses based on it.

This is how you can generate addresses based on a Master Public Key that corresponds to a base derivation path:

```
const wallet = require('ethereumjs-wallet')
const hdkey = require('ethereumjs-wallet/hdkey')

const create_addresses = async (from, to) => {

  const addresses = [];

  const master_public_key = process.env.MASTER_PUBLIC_KEY;

  const hdk = hdkey.fromExtendedKey(master_public_key);

  from = from || 0;
  to = to || 100;

  for (let i = from; i <= to; i++){
    const child = hdk.deriveChild(i);
    const w = wallet.fromExtendedPublicKey( child.publicExtendedKey() );
    const addr = {};
    addr[w.getAddressString()] = `${process.env.BASE_DERIVATION_PATH}/${i}`;
    addresses.push(addr);
  };

  return addresses;
}
```

Assuming the value found in `process.env.MASTER_PUBLIC_KEY` corresponds to the derivation path `m/44'/60'/0`, the above function, when called without any parameters will generate addresses from `m/44'/60'/0/0` to `m/44'/60'/0/100`

Update - getting the master public key:

```
const get_mpk = ( seed, bdp ) => {
  const seed = bip39.mnemonicToSeed(mnemonic)
  const hdk = hdkey.fromMasterSeed(seed);

  const base_derivation_path = bdp || "m/44'/60'/0'/0";
  const base_derived = hdk.derivePath(base_derivation_path);
  const master_public_key = base_derived.publicExtendedKey();
  return master_public_key;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you also provide how can I generate MASTER_PUBLIC_KEY. and than  how  do I withdraw recieved coins?

Comment: I've added the code that generates the `MASTER_PUBLIC_KEY` from seed words and derivation path. Unfortunately, I don't have the code to create and sign transactions in a single place (we're creating the tx online and sign it offline) and I don't have time to put it together now.

Comment: I just want to understand what I need to have to make transactions. How can I understood I need to have private key to make transaction form those adresses. But what private key I need to have ? And how can I use it ?